# SQL syntax error when concatenating query string

Tags: java, mysql

```
try(Connection dbConnection = DBConnectionManager.getIntakeConnection();
PreparedStatement preparedStmtSetMaxStrikeId = dbConnection.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT MAX(strike_id) FROM strike WHERE 'SELECT p.party_type_id,"
    + "p.csa_score,p.party_tn,p.rec_create_date,"
    + "s.strike_id, s.strike_date, s.strike_level, s.strike_status,
       s.appealable,s.appeal_status,s.rec_change_date,s.event_id,
       s.is_email_processed,s.policy_id"
    + "FROM strike s "
    + "INNER JOIN parties p"
    + "ON p.party_id = s.party_id"
    + "WHERE p.account ='"+appealStatus.getSubscriberId()
    +"'AND strike_status = '"+OCIRISConstants.STRIKE_STATUS_ACTIVE+"' ");)
```

The error is below.
Integers in the error are subscriber ids.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0957936101205'AND strike_status = 'ACTIVE'' at line 1

Comment: "a" + "b" + "c" = abc, not a b c. Get it?

Comment: What is `WHERE 'SELECT` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says:

> near '`0957936101205'AND strike_status = 'ACTIVE'`' at line 1

It's actually identifying the `0` following the `'`, which ends the text literal started in the first line, because this is bad SQL:

```sql
SELECT MAX(strike_id) FROM strike WHERE '...'0957936101205'AND strike_status = 'ACTIVE'
--                                          ^^ BAD
```

Here is the code annotated with comments:

```
try(Connection dbConnection = DBConnectionManager.getIntakeConnection();
PreparedStatement preparedStmtSetMaxStrikeId = dbConnection.prepareStatement(
      "SELECT MAX(strike_id) FROM strike WHERE 'SELECT p.party_type_id,"
//                                             ^ What is this? Even without ' it makes no sense
//                                             ^ But it STARTS A TEXT LITERAL
    + "p.csa_score,p.party_tn,p.rec_create_date,"
    + "s.strike_id, s.strike_date, s.strike_level, s.strike_status, s.appealable,s.appeal_status,s.rec_change_date,s.event_id,s.is_email_processed,s.policy_id"
    + "FROM strike s "
//     ^ Missing space, but it's in a text literal so doesn't matter
    + "INNER JOIN parties p"
    + "ON p.party_id = s.party_id"
//     ^ Missing space, but it's in a text literal so doesn't matter
    + "WHERE p.account ='"+appealStatus.getSubscriberId()
//     ^ Missing space, but it's in a text literal so doesn't matter
//                      ^ END TEXT LITERAL from first line
//                         ^ error complains about inserted value 0957936101205
    +"'AND strike_status = '"+OCIRISConstants.STRIKE_STATUS_ACTIVE+"' ");)
//    ^ Starts a new text literal
//     ^ Missing space, but it's in a text literal so doesn't matter
//                         ^ end text literal
//                            ^ would complain about inserted value ACTIVE
//                                                                  ^ Dangling '
```

Also, you shouldn't be using string concatenation to build the SQL, since it'll cause syntax errors and leave you susceptible to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, allowing hackers to steal your data and delete your tables.

Assuming the initial `SELECT MAX( ... WHERE '` is in error, here is a cleaned up version, formatted for clarity:

```
String sql = "SELECT p.party_type_id, p.csa_score, p.party_tn, p.rec_create_date" +
                  ", s.strike_id, s.strike_date, s.strike_level, s.strike_status" +
                  ", s.appealable, s.appeal_status, s.rec_change_date, s.event_id" +
                  ", s.is_email_processed, s.policy_id" +
              " FROM strike s" +
             " INNER JOIN parties p ON p.party_id = s.party_id" +
             " WHERE p.account = ?" +
               " AND strike_status = ?";
try (Connection conn = DBConnectionManager.getIntakeConnection();
     PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setString(1, appealStatus.getSubscriberId());
    stmt.setString(2, OCIRISConstants.STRIKE_STATUS_ACTIVE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification will follow it.

Comment: I want to select the max strike id from strike table keeping subscriber id which is available in parties table under consideration so I have used nested query @Andreas

Answer (score 0):

The specific syntax error there is saying that there should be a space before the `AND` on the last line of the query:

```
+"' AND strike_status // ... etc
   ^ Insert a space here
```

However, you have several other problems there, e.g. you have not got spaces around line breaks, e.g.

```
+ "INNER JOIN parties p"
+ "ON p.party_id = s.party_id"
```

would become

```
+ "INNER JOIN parties pON p.party_id = s.party_id"
```

You should insert more spaces appropriately, either at the start or end of each line.

There are other syntax errors like `WHERE 'SELECT`. You need to check all of your syntax very carefully.

Also: concatenating values into prepared statements somewhat defeats the point of prepared statements. See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) for examples of how to use them correctly.

Comment: The issue is really on the first line with the weird `WHERE 'SELECT` construct.

Comment: @Andreas sure, that's another issue. I've edited to say that OP should check his syntax because there are those errors amongst others. I think that this answer covers the specific error asked about, and then some.